# MTP not working under Android 6

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, linux, connection-issues, usb-connection-mode, mtp

I am running out of Ideas how to get MTP working *again*... I am simply not getting the dialog again on my android, asking me wether I want just charging, or MTP or Picture mode...

**Until most recently, it was easy: Use a USB cable, concect it to my Ubuntu 16.04 Laptop, get the mentioned choice/approval box...** and voilà the Tablet appeared as an MTP device in the Ubuntu ‚file explorer‘ (caja) nicely auto-mounted.

- got an Samsung Galaxy S2 tablet
- running Android 6.01
- it worked until recently in this configuration

I already followed some advice:

- I made the developer options visible (by tapping the about device info thrice)
- enabled USB debugging (which some sources say, is something to watch out for)
- dialed on the phone menu *#0808# → which shows I'am on `(o)AP` and on `MTP + ADB mode` just like I should (this radio box btw only holds its state, if USB debugging is enabled)

also...

- tried different USB ports
- tried different cables
- tried with another device (MacBook. Thus I have no reason to believe, I messed something up on the host machine OS side... Ubuntu is very stable anyway)
- External Store (4kb) under Settings→Applications→“Show System Apps” is on

well, one last clue:

- Settings → Tethering has the USB switch grayed out „USB cable not connected“. Althoug it clearly is. And I can recharge my tablet through it (otherwise I would have certainly noted...)

Device is not rooted. No other glitches.
Are there maybe some log files (now that Dev mode is enabled) to check out what might got wrong?

Not looked/understood ADB yet. So I couldn't tell you, if that works. Anyway, no dialog to choose upon connecting.

I am out of ammo :-( **Thank you for any piece of advice...**

Comment: Revoke the USB debugging authorisation in Developer options? That would disable device recognition and may help in getting back the prompt?

Comment: Just double checking - is *Select USB Config* in developer options set to MTP? Even if it is, try toggling it to some other option , Connect USB and toggle it back to MTP?

Comment: Did you try on a Windows machine also?

Comment: @beeshyams: Forth and back switching form MTP to Charge to PTP etc... no sucess

Comment: @esQmo No Win machine available. But since if worked last week (same host, already under Android 6) and since I don't even see a raw USB device in Ubuntu (i.e. one w/o proper drivers) I think it's unlikely the host is to blame...

Comment: So check the USB connector if the port is totally clean of lint or debris.

Comment: Try different usb cable. Also try on other machine win/linux than you will know where is problem. Also try finding usb connection setting in settings when and when isn't connected vias usb. And I don't know why but try cleaning cache and data for External storage and Media storage from app manager.

Comment: I have same problem, I have fixed it using below app: The answer is:
https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-mtp-enbaler-t3263467

Comment: I already had this kind of trouble with bad cables (good enough to charge but not enough for data). You say you tried with different cables but are sure they worked for data? (charging is not a proof that the cable is good).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try pulling the notification bar down? You should see "Transferring media files via USB", or "Charging via USB, tape for other USB option" 
And if after doing all this the problem remains, download Samsung USB drivers from Samsung website.

[image: This screenshot comes from my Galaxy J5, running Android 6]
[image: this one too].
<sup>Screenshots from my Galaxy J5 (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Comment: precisely that Dialogue is no longer coming up. Also not hiding in the drag-down. The USB device is not even visible [as a raw USB device](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lsusb) (thus it can imho not be an issue on the host...)

Comment: Did you mind checking the connector?